# How to create 2k item (content) programmatically?

Tags: joomla-3.x

is there an API, or i need to insert the records directly in the DB... not sure how to do that

Comment: Have you tried anything of your own or done any research on the matter?

Comment: yes, tried api side but not luck(research), so i'm guessing the only way is insert in db directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is no built-in API for this, you will have to write your own code. A good place to start is to look here in your Joomla installation:
   administrator/components/com_k2/models/item.php

This file is the K2ModelItem and has the functions used to create and save a K2 item into Joomla DB.

```
    function save($front = false)
{

    $mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();
    jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
    jimport('joomla.filesystem.folder');
    jimport('joomla.filesystem.archive');
    ...
```

You could build your own code based on this or (better) write a custom class that would extend K2ModelItem. 
There are different options, it really depends on your project.

Comment: thanks, thats a good idea, i will take a look... i really appreciate your advice

Answer (score 0):

There is not (yet) a direct API (eg webservice or similar). That's something which may be added for Joomla 3.6, but it's still far away.

You would have to write your own code and use the model or table from com_content.

Depending on why you need it and how often, there may be better options than writing own code :)